# Выборка данных из SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Здравствуйте!
Очередная задача не даёт мне покоя...
Имеется таблица в SQLite [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Левый столбец это ID. Задача состоит в следующем, необходимо вывести значения ID=0, например в list, при условии, что значение ячейки равно 1.
Т.е. делаем выборку с ID=1, под данный критерий подходят P1 и P3.
Если ID=2, то P2.
В итоге в list получается не значения 1 и 1 или 1, а P1, P3 или P2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного задержался с ответом, был завал. В моём случае ответ следующий:

```
int result = 0;
Cursor cursor = null;
Cursor cur = null;
String query = null;
String query1 = null;
cursor = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE, null); 
result = cursor.getColumnCount();
        for (int k = 1; k <= result - 1; k++) {
            query = "SELECT P" + k + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE P" + k + " = 1";
            cur = mDB.rawQuery(query, null);
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                String str1 = "P"+k;
                query1 = "SELECT ID, P" + k + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE ID =" + id;
                cursor = mDB.rawQuery(query1, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    String str = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(str1)));
                    return str;
                }
            }
        }
```

Если у кого есть решение лучше, то жду предложений! :)